# NLTK NaiveBayesClassifier input formatting

Tags: python, nltk

I am totally stumped with this issue. I am relatively new to python and NLTK. I am trying to make a naive Bayes classifier and I am not sure if the input should be a list of tuples, or a dictionary or a list which is a tuple of two lists.

The following returns an error that `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`

```
[('maggie: just a push button. and the electric car uses sensors to drive itself. \n', 'notending')]
```

The format below returns the following error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

```
[([['the', 'fire', 'chief', 'says', 'someone', 'started', 'the', 'blaze', 'on', 'purpose', 'as', 'a', 'controlled', 'burn', ',', 'but', 'it', 'quickly', 'got', 'out', 'of', 'hand', '.']], 'notending')]
```

And if I use a dictionary, I get the following error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

```
{'everyone: bye!': 'ending'}
```

I am calling the naive bayes classifier as `classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(d_train)`

I am not sure what is wrong here. Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = list(set(stopwords.words('english')))

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words.split() if word not in stopset])

posids = ['I love this sandwich.', 'I feel very good about these beers.']
negids = ['I hate this sandwich.', 'I feel worst about these beers.']
pos_feats = [(word_feats(f), 'positive') for f in posids ]
neg_feats = [(word_feats(f), 'negative') for f in negids ]
print pos_feats
print neg_feats
trainfeats = pos_feats + neg_feats
classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
```

Take a look at the positive and negative feats

```
[({'I': True, 'love': True, 'sandwich.': True}, 'positive'), ({'I': True, 'feel': True, 'good': True, 'beers.': True}, 'positive')]
[({'I': True, 'hate': True, 'sandwich.': True}, 'negative'), ({'I': True, 'feel': True, 'beers.': True, 'worst': True}, 'negative')]
```

So, If you give the sentence 'I hate everything' to classify

```
print classifier.classify(word_feats('I hate everything'))
```

you will get the result as 'negative'.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work okay. In this case each word is given the 'true' tag. Do you have an idea what would I have to do if I want the classifier to use sentences as such instead of words. ANs also how do I train for the non-true cases?

Comment: if you want to use sentences instead of words you can use, def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(words, True)])

Comment: in general, we remove stop words (and,or,that etc) during classification which will gives us the keyword belonging to that category. if you give stopwords "false" then those values wont be valued during classification.

Comment: Thanks. Will give that a go. Much appreciated. I am still not sure about something. Say I have both positive and negative features for training. I mark the positive ones as true and negative ones as false. I can still train and use the test set to see some statistics. Now say I get a new set of lines, how do I classify that. Since I have one method for positive_word_feats and negative_word_feats, how do I treat the new data now?

Comment: Giving keywords for a category is better than giving the sentence itself.

Comment: Thanks Selva. I should may be explain in more detail. I have a list of transcripts and I want to identify when the speaker changes topic. These are news transcripts, so general finishing statements are like 'coming up next' etc., I have a manually tagged data where I have identified subject transitions. I want the classifier to learn this and classify future passages. I have methods now which tag the marked lines as positive and unmarked ones as negative. and I can also train on this data. How do I work with a new passage now? I Hope its clear. Thanks.

Comment: Just checked the updated answer. I get it now. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: This answer should explain what's going on there, i.e. what the `train` method expects.